# How to avoid redirect on the main log in form on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I add **login** form on my page and i want to add **js** validation if someone **login** with incomplete information. but the problem is when i log and try to null the password or username the **wordpress** redirect the page on the main **login** form. the output that i want is to stay on the current page so that i can make a **js** validation. thanks for the help.

Comment: use ajax.if you love to code on your own..for instant solution search plugin in wordpress repository.

Comment: i dont want to use plugin... ajax? is there any simple solution to avoid the code that will redirect the page if the information on login form is incomplete?

Answer (score 0):

Add this in functions.php

```
    add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'my_front_end_login_fail' );  // hook failed login

    function my_front_end_login_fail( $username ) {
      $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  // where did the post submission come from?
      // if there's a valid referrer, and it's not the default log-in screen
       if ( !empty($referrer) && !strstr($referrer,'wp-login') && !strstr($referrer,'wp-admin') ) {
             wp_redirect( $referrer . '?login=failed' );  // let's append some information (login=failed) to the URL for the theme to use
             exit;
      }
   }
```

Referal url: http://www.wpinsite.com/code-snippets/how-to-redirect-wordpress-failed-logins